# Vague playground error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

I am in the playground, using the following code:

```
import UIKit

struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

var person = Person(firstName: "George", lastName: "Herbert")
```

Its throwing the following error, red stop sign to the right of the last line:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). The process has been left at the
>   point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to
>   the state before expression evaluation.

If I click on the square box to the right it shows the latest value, as if its working correctly.  How do I get rid of that stupid stop sign?  I can't see anything wrong with this simple example.

Comment: I would try closing/reopening Xcode, to see if the problem persists

Comment: Well that did it, but it happens frequently, any idea why?

Comment: Playgrounds are kinda buggy. When they work, they're magical, but a lot goes wrong, far too often, I'm afraid

Comment: I was having this issue as well with Xcode 10.2 and 10.2.1. Downgrading to Xcode 10.1 solved this for me.